Finding regions where function is real
I have a function of multiple variables, something like this or similar:
1/(5184 h j (1 + 2 n) r^3 Ω^4)I (j^3 k + 16 j^3 k l - 
   16 j^2 k Ω^2 + 72 j^2 k r^2 Ω^2 + 
   144 j^2 k n r^2 Ω^2 + 864 k r^2 Ω^4 + 
   7776 k r^4 Ω^4 + 15552 k n r^4 Ω^4 + 
   I √(-4 (-2592 h j r^3 Ω^4 - 5184 h j n r^3 Ω^4) (2592 h j r^3 
Ω^4 + 5184 h j n r^3 Ω^4) + (-I j^3 k - 
         16 I j^3 k l + 16 I j^2 k Ω^2 - 
         72 I j^2 k r^2 Ω^2 - 
         144 I j^2 k n r^2 Ω^2 - 
         864 I k r^2 Ω^4 - 
         7776 I k r^4 Ω^4 - 
         15552 I k n r^4 Ω^4)^2))

How can I find which set of values make it real?
And is there a general way to do this? For example if I have some function I want to know maybe what domains of the inputs make it positive and real?
Edit
I think the domain of the parameters does make a big difference. {j,k,l} are all positive integers and {r,n,h,Ω} are positive reals. Reduce works in general but it's much harder when the parameter domains are specified, which is why I was looking for any alternatives.

Reduce[expr > 0, vars] is the generic way. The more variables, the more complicated expr is: the more time and memory it will take, the more likely that it will run into system limits.

Are {h, j, k, l, n, r, \[CapitalOmega]} assumed real?

As asked by @user64494 , what's the domain of the parameters? Depending on that, the degree of difficulty for answering your question will be quite different, please clarify. The question will be reopened once it meets the standard of the site.

How about \[CapitalOmega]?

also positive real

@Luca:  Should specify if you wish an analytic or numeric "set of values".

You've asking 17 questions and accepted only one answer. People are voluntarily giving you their time and expertise. You should thank them by upvoting helpful answers and accepting the best one that solves your each of your problems.

Maybe we forgot: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the tour! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by clicking the gray triangles, because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by clicking the checkmark sign!

@josh I typically prefer analytic and only resort to numerical when analytic isn't possible

thanks @MichaelE2 although it is not always clear that my problem has been "solved", do I always just accept the best one?

You don't have to, and probably shouldn't, accept an answer that does not answer the problem. It would be good to explain what issues remain, in case the answerer(s) or someone else can solve them. Sometimes problem can't be solved, and such questions won't ever have an accepted answer. The accepted status of an answer, together with the number of upvotes, should guide site visitors who are looking for solutions to the same or similar problem.

Assuming   all symbols  being real except the imaginary unit 'I', preimage of the real line is given by the zero of the coefficent of 'I', the imaginary part of the expression.
The imaginary part is
 1/(2 I) (expr - (expr/.{Complex[a_,b_] :> a- I b })) == 0

$$\frac{k \left(j^3 (16 l+1)+8 j^2 \Omega ^2 \left(9 (2 n+1) r^2-2\right)+864 r^2 \Omega ^4 \left(9 (2 n+1) r^2+1\right)\right)}{5184 h j (2 n+1) r^3 \Omega ^4} \ = \ 0$$
$$ (j^3 (16 l+1)+8 j^2 \Omega ^2 \left(9 (2 n+1) r^2-2\right)+864 r^2 \Omega ^4 \left(9 (2 n+1) r^2+1\right) 
  \ = \ 0$$
You can force the evaluation over positive real symbols (which is suggested by the physical use of the names) by
   $Assumptions = _Symbol >= 0 

    Series[I (expr - (expr /. {Complex[a_, b_] :> a - I b})) // Together //
      Numerator, {r, 0, 4}]

or
   Series[((ComplexExpand[Im[expr], {Re, Im}] // Together // Numerator) ),
          {r, 0, 4}]

both yielding
$$0\ = j^2 k \left(16 \Omega ^2-j (16 l+1)\right)-72 r^2 \left(k \Omega ^2 \left(j^2 (2 n+1)+12 \Omega ^2\right)\right)-7776 r^4 \left(k (2 n+1) \Omega ^4\right)+O(r)^5$$

Unfortunayely, ComplexExpand[Im[expr]] produces k/(6 h j (1 + 2 n) r) + (3 k r)/(2 h j (1 + 2 n)) + (3 k n r)/(  h j (1 + 2 n)) + (j^2 k)/(5184 h (1 + 2 n) r^3 \[CapitalOmega]^4) + ( j^2 k l)/(324 h (1 + 2 n) r^3 \[CapitalOmega]^4) - (j k)/( 324 h (1 + 2 n) r^3 \[CapitalOmega]^2) + (j k)/( 72 h (1 + 2 n) r 

\[CapitalOmega]^2) + (j k n)/( 36 h (1 +     2 n) r \[CapitalOmega]^2) - ((((2592 h j r^3 \[CapitalOmega]^4 +            5184 h j n r^3 \[CapitalOmega]^4) (10368 h j r^3 \ \[CapitalOmega]^4 + 20736 h j n r^3 \[CapitalOmega]^4) - (-j^3 k -    16 j^3 k l + 16 j^2 k \[CapitalOmega]^2 -           72 j^2 k r^2 \[CapitalOmega]^2 -  144 j^2 k n r^2 \[CapitalOmega]^2 -   864 k r^2 \[CapitalOmega]^4 - 7776 k r^4 \[CapitalOmega]^4 -  15552 k n r^4 \[CapitalOmega]^4)^2)^2)^(1/4)  Sin[1/2 Arg[-4 (-2592 h j r^3

\[CapitalOmega]^4 -  5184 h j n r^3 \[CapitalOmega]^4) (2592 h j r^3 \[CapitalOmega]^4 + 5184 h j n r^3 \[CapitalOmega]^4) + (-I j^3 k -            16 I j^3 k l + 16 I j^2 k \[CapitalOmega]^2 -            72 I j^2 k r^2 \[CapitalOmega]^2 -  144 I j^2 k n r^2 \[CapitalOmega]^2 -   864 I k r^2 \[CapitalOmega]^4 -            7776 I k r^4 \[CapitalOmega]^4 -            15552 I k n r^4 \[CapitalOmega]^4)^2]])/(5184 h j (1 +     2 n) r^3 \[CapitalOmega]^4).

I never use ComplexExpand. Very difficult to verify and useful only if all symbols are declared by assumptions.

Well, I understand your guys are eagering to help, but personally I really suggest waiting for a while if a question hasn't become clear enough. Then, @user64494 I'd say your first several comments are not that clear, do you mean Roland's result doesn't look the same as that of ComplexExpand? If so, I'd say this is not a strong evidence, because we all know that, for complicated identity, even Simplify, etc. may have a chance not to simplify it to True. If you believe Roland's output is wrong, can you show a set of specific numeric parameters illustrating the difference?

@xzczd:  You wrote "do you mean Roland's result doesn't look the same as that of ComplexExpand? ". Yes, I do mean it. The command 1/(2 I) (expr - (expr /. {Complex[a_, b_] :> a - I b})) -    Im[expr] /. {h -> 1, j -> 1, k -> 1, l -> 1, n -> 1,    r -> 1, \[CapitalOmega] -> 1} results in (-24409 + Sqrt[353934577])/15552 -   1/2 I ((I (24409 - Sqrt[353934577]))/15552 + (     I (24409 + Sqrt[353934577]))/15552) . Its numeric value equals 1.20969 + 0. I.

@user64494 Now I think it is clear enough :) .

@xzczd: Guy, I am glad to hear it.

@user64494 and Roland, OP has clarified the question, have a look. (And you see it's indeed better to wait for clarification ¯\(ツ)/¯ )

Here is a partial answer under the assumption that all varables are real-valued.
expr = 1/(5184 h j (1 + 2 n) r^3 \[CapitalOmega]^4) I (j^3 k + 
 16 j^3 k l - 16 j^2 k \[CapitalOmega]^2 + 
 72 j^2 k r^2 \[CapitalOmega]^2 + 
 144 j^2 k n r^2 \[CapitalOmega]^2 + 
 864 k r^2 \[CapitalOmega]^4 + 7776 k r^4 \[CapitalOmega]^4 + 
 15552 k n r^4 \[CapitalOmega]^4 + 
 I \[Sqrt](-4 (-2592 h j r^3 \[CapitalOmega]^4 - 
        5184 h j n r^3 \[CapitalOmega]^4) (2592 h j r^3 
\[CapitalOmega]^4 + 5184 h j n r^3 
\[CapitalOmega]^4) + (-I j^3 k - 
        16 I j^3 k l + 16 I j^2 k \[CapitalOmega]^2 - 
        72 I j^2 k r^2 \[CapitalOmega]^2 - 
        144 I j^2 k n r^2 \[CapitalOmega]^2 - 
        864 I k r^2 \[CapitalOmega]^4 - 
        7776 I k r^4 \[CapitalOmega]^4 - 
        15552 I k n r^4 \[CapitalOmega]^4)^2));
Reduce[Im[expr] == 0 && Variables[expr] \[Element] Reals,
 Variables[expr], Complexes]


1.2 MB

Unfortunately,
expr1 = expr /. {h -> h1 + I*h2, j -> j1 + I*j2, k -> k1 + I*k2, 
l -> l1 + I*l2, n -> n1 + I*n2, 
r -> r1 + I*r2, \[CapitalOmega] -> \[CapitalOmega]1 + 
  I*\[CapitalOmega]2};
Reduce[Im[expr1] == 0 && Variables[expr1] \[Element] Reals, Variables[expr1], Complexes]

crashes my comp.
Addition.
Reduce[Im[expr] == 0 && {j, k, l} \[Element]    PositiveIntegers && 
{r, n, h, \[CapitalOmega]} \[Element]  PositiveReals, 
Variables[expr], Complexes]


The output in terms of Roots with its LeafCount be equal to 7214.

Reduce[Im[expr] == 0 &&  Re[expr] > 0 && {j, k, l} \[Element] 
PositiveIntegers && {r, n, h, \[CapitalOmega]} \[Element] 
  PositiveReals, Variables[expr], Complexes]


False

Tha same command with Re[expr] < 0 instead of produces the output of LeafCount be equal to 7214 too.

@The down-voter: What is incorrect in my answer? It is not fair to down vote without any explaining comment.

Well, I understand your guys are eagering to help, but personally I really suggest waiting for a while if a question hasn't become clear enough.

@xzczd: See the addition to my answer.

Documenting the failure of an approach may have value as a comment but is not an answer and none of the looking at why it didn’t work seems to provide benefit. I suppose whoever down-voted was expressing this view. Finally it should be noted that omitting the Complexes yields possibly meaningful results (note this can be expressed as a comment not an “answer”).

@ubpdqn:  You wrote "Finally it should be noted that omitting the Complexes yields possibly meaningful results ". The command  Reduce[Im[expr] == 0 && {j, k, l} \[Element]     PositiveIntegers && {r, n, h, \[CapitalOmega]} \[Element]     PositiveReals, Variables[expr]] produces the same result (Complexes are the domain by default.). Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.
